# C# Registry issue

Tags: c#, object, registry, backgroundworker

This is running in a background worker
The issue appears to be with the registry check if the key FS is missing it errors out.
I'm doing this check just in case someone deletes it even though the installer adds the values.
Also wondering why message boxes aren't working

```
    //I DONT EVEN GET TO THIS MESSAGE BOX BEFORE THE ERROR
    //BUT THE CATCH IS TRIGGERED FROM THE TRY BLOCK
    MessageBox.Show("Entered Version Check");
    try
    {
        //DONT GET TO SEE THIS MESSAGE BOX
        MessageBox.Show("Entered try");
        DirectoryInfo Temp = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetTempPath());
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\My Application Here");
        string val;
        if (rk != null)
            {
                val = rk.GetValue("FS").ToString();
                if (val == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("It appears that you do not have a File Server IP address configured" + Environment.NewLine + "Please login to the admin tools and set it", "No File Server Set", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Comment: According to your comments the error occurs before the first line of code. It's going to be hard to work out what causes the error if you don't show us the code.

Comment: Windows Forms application? Can you even use the GUI from a background thread? Does it work if you do it in the foreground?

Comment: @JohnSaunders yes, MessageBox.Show() calls can be made from background threads, but they won't be modal to the main UI thread. Background threads attempting to directly access controls on the UI thread is dangerous however.

Comment: I believe I can't see the message boxes because it is a background thread but i'm not 100% on it, was trying to use them to debug the code.

It is making it into the try block because the error is triggered within the catch.

Its an issue with my registry check it seems which is why I only posted that part. I have no issue posting all of the code if it will help but I don't believe it will.

If the registry key 'FS' is missing from the registry I get the error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If i add the value to the registry the program works correctly

Comment: Doesn't the debugger work for you? Set some breakpoints.

Comment: I can do the registry check outside the background worker which isn't an issue if need be. I believe the registry check is incorrect though. If the key FS is there but have no value it returns null but if that key isn't there at all, I believe this is my issue because it can't pull the value of FS because FS doesn't exist.

Comment: I moved the registry check outside the background worker and its working correctly which isn't an issue it didn't really need to be in there.

My question now is why does that check fail within a background worker?

Comment: I had the same issue. It gives issue even if we catch the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            val = rk.GetValue("FS").ToString();
```

That's going to bomb if GetValue() returns null.  *First* check for null before you try ToString().  And add a check in the BGW's RunWorkerCompleted event handler so you can verify e.Error.  And don't display message boxes in a worker thread, odds are good that they'll disappear behind the window of another app, including your own.

Answer (score 1):

The most common issue like this I've seen is related to the 64bit registry redirection. Are you running on a 64bit OS, with your application compiled as 32bit? If so, the registry calls will be redirected.

Either look under the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` key for your key, or compile your application as 64bit.

Comment: It is running on 32bit machine